# pagination in struts 1.3.8?

Tags: jsp, pagination, struts-1

I'm using struts1.3.8.
when I'm using scriptlet to get the data in the table and displaying,it is showing all the records at a time. But i want to display per page 10.
 I'm trying to implement pagination concept in jsp page using display tag. But The result always showing is "nothing found to display".
This is the code i'm using..

```
<display:table name="requestScope.SearchForm.searchResult"  class="SearchForm" requestURI="" pagesize="10" >
        <display:column property="policyNumber" title="Policy Number" sortable="true"   />
        <display:column property="version" title="version" sortable="true"  />
    </display:table>
```

Here SearchForm is the form bean and searchResult is the property in that. It is a bean with multiple attributes which i have to display in the form of table.
Is there any mistake in my code?
Is there any other way to implement pagination concept?

Any idea is highly apprecitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented using datatable concept which was pretty easy and useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify appropriate Action in `requestURI` attribute. Read the following lines from displaytag documentation

**If you use this tag in Struts, or in some other framework where the page is included via a jsp:include, you should use the requestURI attribute to indicate where tag generated links should point.**

Refer  section on this link - [Display tag reference](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi saurabh, I have already tried by keeping requestURI="/getSearch.do".. But still no use..

Comment: @Laxmanchowdary - Can you please post your Action,form and its mapping. Also, Can you please try to print the searchResult in the method which forwards the form to this jsp?